# Bash command to truncate bytes off end of file

Tags: bash

I have a file that will always have a fixed 16 byte garbage set of characters appended to the end.

I want to run a bash command to remove those last 16 bytes. I found `truncate`, but a command such as `truncate -s 16 myfile.json` will truncate `myfile.json` entire file size to 16 bytes which isn't what I want. Is there a command for truncating bytes off the end of a file?

Answer (score 7):

When a command does something very close to what you want, it's always worth checking the `man` page:

> SIZE may also be prefixed by one of the following modifying characters: '+' extend by, '-' reduce by, '<' at most, '>' at least, '/' round down to multiple of, '%' round up to multiple of.

So:

```
truncate -s -16 myfile.json
```